# Python If statements are being ignored

Tags: python, api, tweepy

When I run a python tweepy function with the following loop, the if statements below get ignored. The results that are returned are "high", even when they should say "very high" or "medium." It seems y is always turning up "false"  even when it should sometimes be "true", thus changing status from "high". Likewise, flags always turns up as 0.

```
for i in xrange(0, len(ids), segment):

    for follower in client.lookup_users(user_ids=ids[i:i+segment]):
        flags=0
        x='false'
        y='false'
        status=''
        values=[]
        userId = userId
        name =str(follower.name.encode('utf-8'))
        screen_name = str(follower.screen_name.encode('utf-8'))
        background =str(follower.default_profile)
        profilePic = str(follower.default_profile_image)



        #Check if friends to follow ratio is higher than limit set above
        if friendsFollowersRatio>highfriendsFollowRatio:
            highFollow = 'true'
            x = 'true'
        else:
            highFollow = 'false'

        if lowFollowHighFriends == 'true':
            x = 'true'

        if tweetNum >= xNumberOfTweets:
            x = 'true'


        if background=='true' and profilePic=='true':
            flags = flags+2
        if screen_name==name:
             flags= flags+1
        if flags>1:
            y='true'


        if x=='true'and y=='true':
            status = 'very high'
        elif x=='true'and y=='false':
            status='high'
        elif x=='false'and y=='true':
            status='medium'
        #ADD INACTIVE
        else:
            status=' blank'



        #Put stuff here
        userId = userId + 1

        #add values to array
        values.append(userId)
        values.append(name)
        values.append(screen_name)
        values.append(background)
        values.append(profilePic)

 ####Create csv file ######
        #Add values as a new row in the data
        csvFile = open('file.csv','ab')
        #prep file to be written on
        newFile =csv.writer(csvFile)


        newFile.writerow(values)

        #close file
        csvFile.close()
```

Comment: `y` *is* always `'false'` in your code. You set `y = 'false'` at the beginning and never set `y` to anything different.

Comment: Also, why are you using *string* values `'true'` and `'false'` instead of boolean values `True` and `False`?

Comment: Also why do you use integers as string? friendsNum == 2001. Would be better

Comment: I added more code to clarify the issue. I should have added that even without y being changed, the if statements aren't working. Flags, for instance, always returns 0, despite any if statements. I have my reasons for using true and false as strings. These are not actual boolean statements, they are variables that the may later want to record to the csv file

Comment: Howdo you expect us to debug this when you haven't shown us the relevant code?  You're asking us to reason about Booleans (which should _be_ Booleans, by the way, not strings) without revealing what they've been set to.  Come to think of it, how do _you_ know the `if` statements are "being ignored"?  What evidence do you have that `flags` is supposed to be positive in the first place? Or that `friendsFollowersRatio` is sufficiently high?  Or that `lowFollowHighFriends` (which sure sounds like the same thing) is true?  What inputs are you providing?  What outputs are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anywhere that you update the value of `y` so it should always be `'false'` in when you get to the `if` block.  Did you mean to set it instead of `x` in one of the spots above?  With names like 'x' and 'y' here it's tough to guess what you meant them to be, but you are never updating `y` so you should not expect its value to change.

Also, why are you not using `True` and `False` instead of strings containing those as words?  You should perhaps be using the boolean types python provides instead of doing it with strings.

Comment: I edited the question for clarity. It's not just Y, anything in the if statements gets ignored, including flags, for instance.

Comment: @auto Well, I would suggest either trying a debugger or adding `print` statements at key locations to see what values the variables actually have in them.  I assure you the `if` statements are not ignored, but you may not be doing the tests you expect, or you may not have the values you expect.  You're using lots of variables that we can't see getting assigned though, so you're sort of on your own for what those might hold